# Xamarin Hot Reload not working. Currently I am using iOS simulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, hot-reload

Looking at the output, is being initialized and I set the iOS build's Linker Behavior to 'Don't Link'. When I make any changes, it does register as change as seen in Output window and it seems like its' working but I don't see any changes on my simulator.

Comment: What is your system? Windows or MacOS? MacOS is not yet supported. Have you check that the Hot Reload is enabled? You could try the steps in the link to enable it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload

Comment: Hi, I am using Windows. Yes, hot reload is enabled.It should work on Mac as well?
 I watched a video by Microsoft where they were explaining about Hot reload and they were using Mac to build on a simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find a fix. Weird fix though.

So, in order to make  your hot reload work

1. Make sure its enabled through *Tools ==> Options ==> Hot Reload ==> Check on Enable XAML Hot Reload.*
   For Mac, *Tools ==> Add Custom tools ==> Xaml Hot Reload ==> Enable*
2. Right-click on iOS project ==> *Properties ==> iOS build and make sure that the Linker Behavior is selected to 'Don't Link'.*
   For Mac, *Options ==> iOS build ==> Set Linker Behavior to Dont Link*.
   If you are building into a physical iOS device, type *--interpreter* under Additional mtouch arguments field.
3. Open solution from the folder where it resides. Opening solution from open project page from VS will not work.

Comment: incredibly in 2021 this is still the only workaround (especially point 3.) wow

Comment: i know right? I was surprised that this was the solution

Comment: This is completely broken on iOS in 16.10.x and 16.11 preview 2.0. Confirmed it works using the older version 16.9.0. Step 3 is not a factor in my case.

Comment: @bcr see my answer. maybe can help you also

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Mac 8.10.x and Vs Windows 16.10.x stopped working in general and none of the answers help. Actually when you open a new project from the template, Hot Reload is working fine. So it doesn't work for the existing older projects. I have opened cs.proj files of IOS project on both my existing project and the new test project, compared each settings and applied settings exactly as it was on the test project to my existing project, after that hot reload works fine. I cannot say which setting was exactly.

Settings I removed

[image]

settings I replaced

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Emil. Actually even a new app from the template (single page) doesn't work for me at all. VS 16.10.3 to an iOS simulator on the Mac is my latest attempt.

Comment: Using the same template on VS for Mac (blank app) does work for me, changes only, using the same simulator.

Comment: There appears to be a fix on deck: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Hot-Reload-is-not-working-for-XamarinFo/1436164