# Xamarin iPhone simulator doesn't show live code changes

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I'm trying to make code changes while using the iPhone simulator it doesn't show the changes .. I tried to reset the iPhone simulator, reconnect to the mac, running the simulator on Xcode and then with Windows Visual Studio. Nothing helped ..

Comment: code changes or xaml changes?

Comment: XAML changes, I think code changes requires a restart.

Comment: have your read the docs and followed the instructions?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload

Comment: Yes, it used to work for me.. I have no idea what happened that it suddenly stopped working...

Comment: FWIW Hot Reload on iOS hasn't worked for me for a few months

Comment: It worked for me 2 days ago, I used it since I started Xamarin (2 weeks ago).

Comment: Refer to this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255900/xamarin-hot-reload-not-working-currently-i-am-using-ios-simulator).

Comment: Didn't help me :( I'm trying to fix it for days ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the new Xamarin packages from GitHub made the problem, so I reinstalled the older packages and now it works :) (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778)